# The reason why I have to create int array instead of pass one directly as argument?

Tags: java, arrays

The closest one I can find is this thread:

[How to pass int array as an argument to a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109147/how-to-pass-int-array-as-an-argument-to-a-constructor)

The answer is clear, you define an int[] tempArray and use that tempArray as argument. However, my question is **why** cannot I write the int array directly as argument.

The code example is like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    NewClass test = new NewClass();
    // int[] tempArray = {1, 2, 3};
    // test.doSomething(tempArray);
    test.doSomething({1, 2, 3});
}
```

Comment: you need to do `new int[] {1,2,3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can**. But the syntax for doing so requires `new int[]`, because you can't use the *syntactic sugar* available with a **declaration**. Something like,

```
test.doSomething(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do so, you can use variable arguments. Make your `test.doSomething()` method like this:

```
void doSomething(int... arguments)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can pass the integers without requiring the new syntax. The compiler will take care of them.

```
test.doSomething(1, 2, 3);
test.doSomething(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Both works now. Inside the method, the compiler automatically makes arguments as an array, so no change in the logic too.

Answer (score 0):

There won;t be any errors if you use the right syntax and pass the array directly to the method.
It should be like

```
test.doSomething(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
```